# Can't get natural join to work with given expression? MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    maker, model
FROM Product NATURAL JOIN 

    (SELECT 
        model
    FROM PC
    WHERE (speed >= 3.0)

    UNION

    SELECT
        model
    FROM Laptop
    WHERE (speed >= 3.0))
```

PC and Laptop are tables with relations (model, speed) : str, int

Product has relation (maker, model) : str, int

What I want to do:

https://gyazo.com/2fe0ead81635c0b6feb6074de2566061

Comment: what was the error ?

Comment: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: what if you add alias `SELECT 
        model
    FROM PC
    WHERE (speed >= 3.0) as a` and `SELECT
        model
    FROM Laptop
    WHERE (speed >= 3.0)) as b` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    SELECT 
        maker, model
    FROM Product AS pd NATURAL JOIN 

        (SELECT 
            model
        FROM PC
        WHERE (speed >= 3.0) 

        UNION

        SELECT
            model
        FROM Laptop
        WHERE (speed >= 3.0) 
        ) as result
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as pc      UNION      SELECT         model     FROM Laptop     WHERE (speed >= 3' at line 8